# How to insert function into PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Please help me with this PHP array issue...

I have a function that outputs values like so: 1,2,5,15,21 etc...

When I use a simple array like this:

```
<?php
$fruits=array("Apples","Oranges","Bananas");
echo "I like " . $fruits[0] . ", " . $fruits[1] . " and " . $fruits[2] . ".";
?>
```

Which gives: "I like Apples, Oranges and Bananas."

And I put my function in it as such:

```
<?php
$my_func = my_function_output();
$fruits=array( $my_func );
echo "I like " . $fruits[0] . ", " . $fruits[1] . " and " . $fruits[2] . ".";
?>
```

The $my_func gives, say, 1,5,7 - then for $fruits[0] I get "1,5,7" instead of getting just the first "1", and for $fruits[1] and $fruits[2] I get nothing instead of 5 and 7 respectively...

Is there a way of getting each array position to be only one of the values from the function? - I can modify the function's output to a different format if needed.

The function basically fetches WordPress user id's;

```
function my_function_output($id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $count = 0;
    $site_user = get_user_name_by_id($id);
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'site_users';

    $user_list = array();
    while($site_user) {
        $site_user = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user FROM $tablename WHERE site_user = '".$site_user."'");
        if($site_user) {
            $user_list[] = $site_user;
        }
    }

    return $user_list;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're missing a dollar symbol off your return statement.. `return $user_list;`

Comment: `return user_list;` should be `return $user_list;`

Comment: Yes, got accidentally removed here... That's not the issue though, - how can I make this function return an array that will fit as such into the array mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to reflect. Have you tried `var_dump`ing or `print_r`ing the return value of your function? `$my_func = my_function_output(); var_dump($my_func);`

Comment: Edited. Should I put the var_dump($my_func); inside the array instead of the plain variable? Thanks.

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: Rename your "$site_user = get_user_name_by_id($id);" by other name. Maybe a conflict with the "$site_user" in your while

Comment: Niels, the intended output is a numerical array like: 1,5,10... Portekoi, I tried, all the same.

Comment: Assuming I understood your code correctly: my_function_output($id) returns an array which you store in $my_func. But you later convert array to another array in $fruits=array( $my_func ); which I think may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an array and you are assigning it to a variable inside ANOTHER array.

```
// here $my_func is an array, the return of $my_custom_func
$my_func = $my_custom_func();
// now my fruits is an array with just ONE element which is another array with your ids.
$fruits = array($my_func);
```

Try assigning the value returned by the function directly do the $fruits var. Like that:

```
$fruits = $my_custom_func();
```

or even

```
$my_func = $my_custom_func();
$fruits = $my_func; // without array()
```